# Is the group of invertible elements in $\mathbb{Z}/8\mathbb{Z}$ isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$ or to the symmetry group of the rectangle?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, group-isomorphism

> Problem: Is the group $g(8) = \{[1], [3], [5], [7]\}$ isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_4$ or to the symmetry group of the rectangle?

Attempt: I know that $g(8)$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_4$ because I compare the multiplication tables, and they look the same.

I know that $g(8)$ is not cyclic, and I know that the symmetry group of the rectangle is not cyclic since every non-identity element has order 2. Does that mean they are not isomorphic?

Can anyone help me verify the last part.
Thank you.

Comment: Why do you say $g(8)$ is not cyclic?

Comment: the books says it is not cyclic.

Comment: why do you say it is wrong?

Comment: But $\mathbb{Z}_4$ *is* cyclic, so $g(8)$ can't be isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_4$.

Comment: So if two groups are not cyclic does that means they are not isomorphic?

Comment: If one group is cyclic and the other isn't, then they aren't isomorphic: Morally, groups are isomorphic if they have all the same structural properties.

Comment: user1456 if I remember well it is possible to write/prove the explicit isomorphism as a solution of your problem, since this is a classic exercise in group theory.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

We need to look at groups of $4$ elements: the set of invertible  elements of $\mathbb Z_8$ is a multiplicative group of order four, and there are only *two* such groups of order four, up to isomorphism: $\mathbb Z_4,$ or the Klein-4 group.

So your group must be isomorphic to $\mathbb Z_4$ or else to the Klein-4 group.

Since your group is not cyclic, it cannot be isomorphic to $\mathbb Z_4$, which *is* cyclic. (Any group that is isomorphic to a cyclic group is necessarily also cyclic).

That leaves only the Klein-4 group, which is NOT cyclic: I'd suggest you compare the group tables of your group and the Klein-4 group to convince yourself that they are isomorphic. The Klein-4 group is isomorphic to $\mathbb Z_2 \times \mathbb Z_2$.

Comment: I'm not smart enough to see why this has 6 downvotes and is accepted, so why does it?

Comment: Because it was targeted with downvoters by two users with multiple sockpuppet accounts, @SomeGuy.  Most of those accounts have been deleted.  But if you don't trust the answer, feel free to vote in whatever manner you want.  Note that the Klein 4-group $\equiv \mathbb Z_2 \times \mathbb Z_2$, as you see in the answer below.  Don't rely only on vote counts to judge the merit of answers.

Answer (score 4):

There are only two groups of order four, up to isomorphism: $\mathbb Z_4$ and $\mathbb Z_2 \times \mathbb Z_2$. You can distinguish them because $\mathbb Z_4$ has two elements of order four, one element of order two and the identity. On the other hand, $\mathbb Z_2 \times \mathbb Z_2$ has three elements of order two and the identity.